# How to implement Ruby's unpack in Rust?

Tags: rust

I'm struggling to figure out how to implement the following `unpack('IIII')` Ruby statement in Rust.

```rb
require 'digest'

md5_digest_unpacked = Digest::MD5.digest(someString + "\x00").unpack('IIII')
```

I have gotten as far as generating the md5 portion with the following. The digests are the same between Ruby and Rust.

```rust
let digest = md5::compute(format!("{}{}", &someString, "\x00"));
```

However, I'm the not sure how to implement `unpack('IIII')`.

Comment: `unpack()` can't be implemented with the same signature as it's too dynamic for Rust. The return type depends on the argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know Rust does not have a drop-in replacement for unpack, but there are two ways to get equivalent behavior here.

#### The Safe Way

```rs
use std::mem;
use std::convert::TryInto;

let mut dest = [0u32; 4];
let mut iter = digest.0.chunks(mem::size_of::<u32>())
    .map(|chunk| u32::from_ne_bytes(chunk.try_into().unwrap()));
dest.fill_with(|| iter.next().unwrap());
let [a, b, c, d] = dest;
```

The upside is that it's safe, the downside is that there are a couple unwraps required but those are infallible given that `digest.0` is `[u8; 16]`, and should be optimized out.

#### The Unsafe Way

Since you're converting to the native endian, you can just transmute the digest:

```rs
let [a, b, c, d] = unsafe { std::mem::transmute::<_, [u32; 4]>(digest.0) };
```

This transmute is safe because `[u32; 4]` and `[u8; 16]` have the same size and are both POD. You can find safe wrappers for these kinds of conversions through the [`bytemuck`](https://docs.rs/bytemuck/latest/bytemuck/index.html#) crate if you're fine with adding another dependency.

Edit: with `-C opt-level=3`, both methods have the [same generated assembly](https://rust.godbolt.org/z/1sKqfTqfo).

Comment: Why mess with iterators? `u32::from_ne_bytes(digest[..4].try_into().unwrap())` (also, the transmute version should not compile).

Comment: You could write out the individual calls to `from_ne_bytes` if you wanted to, but I like to stay DRY as much as possible. Also the transmute example [does indeed compile](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7956a60090724fd921b6db1d084e622c).

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that the underlying type is `u8`.

Comment: @cdhowie you're mixing up pointer casts with transmuting by value. The docs for transmute explicitly say alignment is not a concern. Since we're assigning to new variables, those variables will have the proper alignment for the operation to be sound.

Comment: @IanS. Ah right, I still sometimes confuse slices with arrays since I don't use arrays very much.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! My unit test in Rust is passing the same as in Ruby. I was trying to use the `bincode`  and `byteorder` crates with no luck.